# Sum of the this sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, discrete-mathematics

This question I tried many times but the answer doesn't 
Come at all.

It is related with analysis and discrete mathematics.

Here are some natural number $1$ to $20$.

Let the $a_n(1 \le n \le 20)$

which is rearrangement of the numer $1 $to $20$.

Find the max of the $\sum_{i=1}^{19} |a_{i} -a_{i+1}|$

Why this answer is 199?

Comment: To maximize the sum, you want to vary your values as much as possible, i.e., a sequence like $20, 1, 19, 2, ..., 11, 10$. The sum of the absolute values of differences of this sequence is $19+18+...+1=\frac{19\cdot20}2=190$

Comment: Yes it would be, so the 19+ 17 +15 +13 ...+1 =100, but this was not the answer. Actually  I tried like you when the first time, but the answer is not that.

Comment: No, $19-1=18,$ not $17$.

Comment: Oops my mistake. Anyway the 190 is not the answer. Yes intutively your answer is correct. I'm agree yours is correct. But it is weired that why the answer is 199

Comment: It's not possible to get above $190$ my guy.

Comment: The general answer is $\lfloor \frac{n^2}2 \rfloor-1$, see http://oeis.org/A047838
For $n=20$ you get indeed $199$.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612553/sum-of-difference-of-numbers-in-an-arrangement-of-the-numbers-0-1-2-cdots-n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sequence yielding $199$ is
$$11,1,12,2,13,3,14,4,15,5,16,6,17,7,18,8,19,9,20,10.$$

As to why $199$ is indeed the maximum: It is clear that in every even spot you need a number in $\{1,\ldots,10\}$ while you need a number in $\{11,\ldots,20\}$ in every odd spot to maximize the sum (or vice versa, of course). Hence if the sum would be circular (add $|a_{20} - a_1|$ to the sum), every number in $\{11,\ldots,20\}$ gets added twice and every number in $\{1,\ldots,10\}$ gets subtracted twice. This results in
$$20 \cdot 19 - 2 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 = 200$$
for the circular sum. Making $|a_{20} - a_1|$ smallest possible, i.e. 1, yields a maximum of $199$ for the non-circular sum. So as long as you put $a_1 = 11$ and $a_{20} = 10$ and alternate between large and small numbers, you will always get $199$.